# How do you update the app.json manifest on a running heroku app?

Tags: git, heroku, deployment

I am using Heroku Pipelines connected to GitHub.

I have three different environments:
- `Reviews` (where all my pull requests are automatically deployed to once my CI tests are successful)
- `Staging` (where my master branch is deployed to)
- `Production` (my production environment)

My `Review` apps are created and destroyed as I pull and merge branches. My `Staging` and `Production` apps are always the same. `Staging` gets updated when my master branch is updated, and then I can manually decide to promote that code to `Production`.

This is all great! Except I am facing a issue with my `app.json` file.

When developing new branches, I often use new heroku addons i.e. a Redis db or new monitoring tools. I do this by updating my `app.json` file. Example:

```
"addons": [
  "logentries:le_tryit",
  "newrelic:wayne",
  {
    "plan": "mongolab:sandbox",
    "as": "MONGODB_URI"
  },
  {
    "plan": "heroku-redis:hobby-dev",
    "as": "REDIS_SESSIONS_URI"
  }
]
```

Once a create a pull request, a app is created in `Reviews` and I can see my new addons. Unfortunately, when I merge my branch with master, `app.json` doesn't seem to run again on my `Staging` environment (and subsequently in my `Production` environment.

Is there a way to re-run the `app.json` manifest in an existing heroku app? and can they be automated with each new deploy?

If not, are there reasons for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're asking. The `app.json` is only parsed when creating a new Heroku app, not when re-deploying one. The reason is that it could cause unwanted side effects to a production application.

EG: What would happen if you remove a line from the `app.json` file and push that to an existing Heroku app? Should Heroku delete your addon (potentially destroying lots of data?)

Instead, what you should do is this: when you cut a production release, if you need to use new addons or change them, do it via the CLI manually.

For instance:

```
$ heroku addons:create heroku-redis
```

Comment: Thanks for this input @rdegges. I thought about it a little more and agree with you, it is most likely bad practice to have existing apps update from the app.json. Just means that you if you add new addons, you need to manually add them (CLI/Dashboard) to your existing apps (if you are using pipelines or similar.

Comment: Some [Heroku documentation confirming this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-in-app-json): *Changing app.json won’t update the settings of existing apps, you will need to use the `heroku buildpacks` command instead.*